# Recommendations for Github repository

Tags: github, repository

I am starting to use Github for one of my projects. I am wondering which approach is better.

1. Should I use separate repositories for my production server code and for developing code? Should I commit into different repo?
2. Having 2 different branches in a single repository and one is development and another is production?

Comment: Having multiple branches is definitely a better approach.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer, if it helped you  to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should use branches, the scenario you are describing is exactly what they were designed to support.

The ability to merge and rebase branches will greatly help you to streamline your development process.

[Here's](https://dev.to/maxwell_dev/the-git-rebase-introduction-i-wish-id-had) a nice git rebase introduction that I recently stumbled upon, I thought you might find it helpful.